# Infinite loop execute while using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, infinite-loop

I am using following code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_temp_ecs $$
CREATE 
    TRIGGER `after_insert_temp_ecs` AFTER insert ON `ecs` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set @count =1;
WHILE(@count<=NEW.installments) THEN
insert into temp_ecs (amount_temp,_date_temp,id,name,installments) values(NEW.amount,(date_add(NEW._date,interval @count month)),NEW.id,NEW.name,NEW.installments);
set @count=@count+1;
END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I use it infinite loop execute. What's the error in the code

Comment: what is the possible value of `NEW.installments`?

Comment: it will lie between 1 to 12 int

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose `NEW.installments = 1`. Now consider this block

```
set @count =1;
WHILE(@count<=NEW.installments) THEN
insert into temp_ecs (amount_temp,_date_temp,id,name,installments) values(NEW.amount,(date_add(NEW._date,interval @count month)),NEW.id,NEW.name,NEW.installments);
set @count=@count+1;
END WHILE;
```

The trigger will insert one more record and then `@count` will be increased to 2, the while condition will not hold any more (`WHILE(@count<=NEW.installments)`) and the trigger will finish.

Note that the trigger inserted one new row, with `NEW.installments = 1`. For this additional row, the trigger will run again, will insert one more row, and this keeps going forever.

Comment: @Amrita, first of all, you did not describe what you want to do in your original posting, you just asked what was the error with your trigger code. So you should _post an other question_ describing what you want to do and asking how you can do it. Second, when you'll ask a new question, please try to describe what you want in proper, understandable English, because this comment does not make any sense to me.